# React-select : Is it possible to set the width of the controller to 100%?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, react-select

I'm trying to use react-select in a form that uses boostrap 3. 
I couldn't find a way to tell the control to have a width of 100%.

I've tried setting autoSize to false. Didn't work. 
I've also tried to set wrapperStyle or style options to {width: '100%'}, still with no luck.

Any one know how to do it ?

Comment: You can look through the react-select css file to see where it sets width. Most components have width: 100%, except we see that `Select-placeholder, .Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value { max-width: 100% }`. Try setting `width: 100%` on that selector instead in your css.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help Sohan, you directed me in the right direction. The problem in fact wasn't in react-select, but in the div hosting it. Bootstrap must have calculated the width when the react-select control had not been calculated. Setting the div to width: 100% did the trick.